# Ember disconnectOutlet does not remove modal template from the DOM

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have simple implementation of modal dialog that accepts a model for details. Since I cannot use a single template for different models, I created a separate modal for each one.

On Route A I used this code to display my modal:

```
openAcctRegModal: function(request) {
        this.controllerFor('modal-acct-reg').set('model', request);
        return this.render('modal-acct-reg', { into: 'application', outlet: 'modal' });
    }
```

To close it, I use a closeModal function on the application route as shown below:

```
closeModal: function() {
        return this.disconnectOutlet({ outlet: 'modal', parentView: 'application'});
    }
```

These two works fine, so I did a similar thing to another route say Route B:

```
 openModal: function(request) {
        this.controllerFor('modal-request').set('model', request);
        return this.render('modal-request', { into: 'application', outlet: 'modal' });
    }
```

However this other one does not work as expected. Unlike in Route A, calling disconnectOutlet in Route B does not completely remove the modal template from the DOM.

Comment: Can you provide a sample jsbin/jsfiddle demo for debugging purpose?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but unfortunately I cannot replicate the issue in a simpler application. The test application works just fine. I'm working with yeoman so my code is separated into different files. I'm merely hoping that someone has already encountered this issue before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encountered it again in a simpler modal dialog. Turned out the div element that has the modal CSS class was not properly closed.